# Задать всем вложенным элементам дополнительный паддинг

Tags: javascript, html, css

Имеется `div` с вложенными `div`.

Разметка такая:

```
<div class="found-item">
    <a href="">
        <div class="user-name clearfix">
            <div class="pull-left">                                           
                <div>Руководитель группы веб-разработки</div>
            </div>                                       
        </div>
    </a>
    <div class="user-group">
        <span class="icons icon-group"></span>
        <a href="">Управление информационных технологий</a>
    </div>
    <div class="user-group user-group-inserted">
        <span class="icons icon-group"></span>
        <a href="">Группа веб-разработки</a>
    </div>
    <div class="user-group user-group-inserted-1">
        <span class="icons icon-group"></span>
        <a href="">Группа веб-разработки</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

У каждого вложенного `div` должен увеличиваться `padding` на 10рх.

Стили:

```
.found-item {
    background: #fff;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #b6b6ba;
}
.found-item .user-group {
    padding: 0 20px;
}
.found-item .user-group-inserted {
    padding-left: 30px;
}
.found-item .user-group-inserted-1 {
    padding-left: 40px;
}
```

Сейчас для каждого последующего `div` задан отдельный класс.
Возможно как это реализовать без добавления отдельного класса? Есть ли решение с помощью css или тут нужен js ?

[Полный код](https://jsfiddle.net/lilubanana/keubhkvb/)

Это должно выглядеть так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: правильнее было бы изменить разметку, сделав каждый следующий блок вложенным (по принципу многоуровневого списка). по семантике это было бы тоже вернее. и тогда общее правило отступа их сдвигало бы на равное кол-во пикселей от родителя

Comment: здесь больше подошел бы вложенный список

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Доброго времени суток.
Попробуйте так:

```
.found-item > div{
   padding:...
}
```

Более подробно можете почитать по ссылке [тут](http://htmlbook.ru/samcss/dochernie-selektory)

Селектор 1 > Селектор 2 { Описание правил стиля }

Стиль применяется к Селектору 2, но только в том случае, если он является дочерним для Селектора 1.

**Правка:**
Да прошу прощения, напутал чуть. Если вам надо уйти от классов именно для приведенного вами списка (т.е. из трех элементов), то как вариант:

```
    .found-item {
background: #fff;
margin: 5px;
padding: 5px 0;
border-bottom: 1px solid #b6b6ba;
      }
.found-item > div{
   padding-left: 10px;
}
.found-item div + div{
   padding-left:20px;
}
.found-item div + div + div{
   padding-left:30px;
}
```

а если список будет формироваться динамически и количество элементов будет изменяемо, то да надо будет использовать js или средства языка, на котором пишется сайт.

Comment: этот вариант не подходит, т.к. в `.found-item` содержится много `div`. в данном случае `padding` добавится всем дивам одинаковый. а необходимо чтобы для каждого последующего `padding` увеличивался. надеюсь понятно объясняю)

Comment: спасибо, сделала пока так. хотя согласна что разметку надо поменять

Answer (score 1):

можно попробовать с jquery:

```
var x = $( ".user-group" ).toArray();
var pad=0;
for(var i=0; i<x.length;i++){
$(x[i]).css("padding-left", (pad+10)+"px");
pad +=10;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/46tup24k/1/)

> [@Grundy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/546443/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3/546493?noredirect=1#comment697077_546493) 
>   можно и только `.css` просто менее наглядно:

```
$( ".user-group").css("padding-left", function( index, value ) {
    return (index+1) * 10;
});
```

Comment: не нужен toArray и цикл не нужен и переменная не нужна, хватит одного вызова [функции css](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName-function)

Comment: там объект необязательно, можно так же двумя параметрами - именем свойства и функцией. И, на самом деле, намного более наглядно, чем цикл с посторонней переменной и постоянным созданием объекта jQuery.

Comment: @Grundy Возможно, спорить не буду..

Answer (score 1):

Еще как вариант использование препроцессоров `less`, `sass`

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/cg34as14/)

```
<div class="b">
  <div class="b__item">text</div>
  <div class="b__item">text</div>
  <div class="b__item">text</div>
  <div class="b__item">text</div>
  <div class="b__item">text</div>
  <div class="b__item">text</div>
  <div class="b__item">text</div>
  <div class="b__item">text</div>
  <div class="b__item">text</div>
  <div class="b__item">text</div>
  <div class="b__item">text</div>
  <div class="b__item">text</div>
  <div class="b__item">text</div>
  <div class="b__item">text</div>
  <div class="b__item">text</div>
  <div class="b__item">text</div>
  <div class="b__item">text</div>
  <div class="b__item">text</div>
</div>

.b {
  background: #fff;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #b6b6ba;
}

.b__item {
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;    
}

$div: 100; /* количество блоков */

@for $i from 1 through $div {
  .b__item:nth-of-type(#{$i}) {
    padding-left: $i * 10px;
  }
}
```

Comment: это если знаешь количество дивов можно, а не зная - генерируя заведомо большое число можно либо промахнуться и не угадать и количество будет больше, либо нагенерировать кучу стилей большинство из которых будут просто место занимать

Comment: Об этом не подумал.  Все таки наиболее правильным вариантом - это изменить html структуру сделав каждый следующий блок вложенным, как предложил @lexxl.